# Getting runtime error 91 when trying to get Google maps to calculate distance

Tags: excel, vba, google-maps, runtime-error

I am trying to get som info from Google maps into a spreadsheet, but I am getting a runtime error when I run the code and the debug mode isnt helping much.

I have looked at other articles and they say something about declairing the variables, but I cant find where to do this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GoogleMaps()

Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim journey As IXMLDOMNode

Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60

myRequest.Open "GET", 
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & 
Range("B1").Value & "&destinations=" & Range("B2").Value & 
"&key=MYOWNAPIKEY
myRequest.send

Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText

Set journey = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//leg/duration/value")

Range("B3").Value = journey.Text

Set journey = Nothing
Set myDomDoc = Nothing
Set myRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

The runtime error occurs at the Range("B3").Value = journey.Text line, but I cant figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Is it correct that you're missing a " at "&key=MYOWNAPIKEY ?

Comment: Yes it is just an error in the code above. I have it in the real code. I just did not want to show my API key here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works like a charm.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GoogleMaps()

Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim journey As IXMLDOMNode
Dim journey2 As IXMLDOMNode

Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60
myRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml? 
origins=" & Range("I1").Value & "&destinations=" & Range("I2").Value & 
"&key=MYOWNKEY"
myRequest.send
Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText
Set journey = 
myDomDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/
duration/value")
Set journey2 = 
myDomDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/
distance/value")

Range("B3").Value = journey.Text / 60
Range("B4").Value = journey2.Text / 1000

Set journey = Nothing
Set myDomDoc = Nothing
Set myRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: you can mark answer as correct, due to help to others in future

Comment: I tried to do that but got a message that I could do it tomorrow. I think it is because I answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be, that there is not such node `//leg/duration/value`, in this case as described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757846(v%3Dvs.85) `SelectSingleNode` method returns Null.

Try to check it by this code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GoogleMaps()

Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim journey As IXMLDOMNode

Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60

myRequest.Open "GET", 
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & 
Range("B1").Value & "&destinations=" & Range("B2").Value & "key=MYOWNAPIKEY"
myRequest.send

Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText

Set journey = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//leg/duration/value")
If journey is Null _
Then
    MsgBox "No such node found"
End If
Range("B3").Value = journey.Text

Set journey = Nothing
Set myDomDoc = Nothing
Set myRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```